# how to decode the Stack Exchange API response

Tags: java, json, stackexchange-api

I am trying to retrieve the response of stack exchange api like
[[http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow]](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow%5d)

I am using the following code  to retrieve the response

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class RetrieveAllTag {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow");
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        finally {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the response in decoded form as 
���n� �߅\f]as��DՊ�I��/�m�(��*Ʃ���Kc���

I found the similar question [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808901/problems-with-decoding-stack-exchange-api-response]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808901/problems-with-decoding-stack-exchange-api-response%5d) , 
but I didn't find any answers for the question.

How to decode the api response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is compressed. You need to send it through an unzip stream, like

```
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

...
InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
content = new GZIPInputStream(content);
...
```

You should also check the content encoding first, and only wrap the stream into a `GZIPInputStream` if the encoding actually **is** `gzip` - some proxies transparently already uncompress the stream.

See [SOQuery.java](https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/blob/master/Java/SOQuery/src/net/littletux/SOQuery.java) for a complete sample, even though this is using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` rather than the apache client.